# DB2 SELECT Statement with LIKE using ""

Tags: sql, db2

I need to build a query to select records in a column that stores my app's payloads in DB2.

The column is set as **varchar(2000)**.

The String that I need to search is:

```
userName": ""
```

So a LIKE statement on my select would be something like:

```
WHERE MyTable.column LIKE '%userName": ""%'
```

My problem is with the **""** inside the LIKE ... it is not bringing the records

Comment: Not the best way to search JSON content...but it should be working.  What problem do you have?

Comment: What's the result of `SELECT * FROM (VALUES 'userName": ""') MYTABLE (COLUMN) WHERE COLUMN LIKE 'userName": ""%'`? Something unexpected?

Comment: And are you sure that the record has that string you were looking for? You could also try `\"\"`. Sometimes `""` is used to escape the double quote.

Comment: @MarkBarinstein, the result is the following : `userName": ""`

Comment: @data_henrik, if I use `MyTable.column LIKE '%userName": \"\"%'` ... no records are returned

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen, no records are returning with `WHERE MyTable.column LIKE '%userName": ""%'`

Comment: Add the actual document to your question. Are you sure it is encoded right?

Comment: Db2 for LUW does return the expected output like [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/5FQhbk5A). What's your Db2 platform and version? Can you provide some similar reproducible example to check?